# Multi-functional array last row same results

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

So.. hi guys. I have a problem with my code, which consists of multi-dimensional arrays having the same result ..

Code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> students;
    double A[6][5];

    students.resize(5);

    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) {
        students[i-1] = i;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++) {
            cin >> A[i][j];
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    for(int j=0;j<5;j++) {
        A[5][j] = (A[i][0] + A[i+1][0] + A[i+2][0] + A[i+3][0] + A[i+4][0]) / 5.0;
    }

    cout << A[5][0] << endl;
    cout << A[5][1] << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Summarily i have a multi-functional array that has 6 rows and 5 columns.. The 6 row is used to calculate average.. So i introduce all marks in 5 rows and 5 columns .. The problem is that when i print out every average(in code for example first average and second), that's the same and i can't understand why.

Comment: The thing is whatever be the value of `j` in the loop you are adding only `a[0][0]+a[1][0]+a[2][0]+a[3][0]+a[4][0]`

Comment: shouldnt it be `A[5][j] = (A[0][j] + A[1][j] + A[2][j] + A[3][j] + A[4][j]) / 5.0;`?

Comment: Oh .. i changed so fast to 0 and i didn't analyze that .. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yea i want to but i have reputation 11 .. and i need at least 15 to do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this

```
for(int j=0;j<5;j++) 
{
    A[5][j] = (A[i][0] + A[i+1][0] + A[i+2][0] + A[i+3][0] + A[i+4][0]) / 5.0;
}
```

You are repeatedly assigning the value of `a[0][0]+a[1][0]+a[2][0]+a[3][0]+a[4][0]` in each element of last row.
You need to change that to

```
for(int j=0;j<5;j++) 
{
    A[5][j] = (A[i][j] + A[i+1][j] + A[i+2][j] + A[i+3][j] + A[i+4][j]) / 5.0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
A[5][j] = (A[i][0] + A[i+1][0] + A[i+2][0] + A[i+3][0] + A[i+4][0]) / 5.0;
```

you are not using `j` to index the column of your 2D array in the computation.

Change it to:

```
A[5][j] = (A[i][j] + A[i+1][j] + A[i+2][j] + A[i+3][j] + A[i+4][j]) / 5.0;
```